# Oracle doctrine2 Group by

Tags: oracle, doctrine-orm, oracle11g

I dont know oracle much. I recently had to migrate an application made in PHP/MySQL to PHP/Oracle. As I was using Doctrine2, I thought that would not be that hard, but I am getting stuck in this query here. This is the SQL generated by Doctrine2 :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  (SELECT b0_.id     AS id0,
  b0_.created      AS created1,
  b1_.businessName AS businessName2,
  b1_.isVerified   AS isVerified3,
  COUNT(b2_.id)    AS sclr4
FROM br_merchants b1_
INNER JOIN br_user b0_
ON b1_.id = b0_.id
LEFT JOIN br_campaigns b2_
ON b1_.id = b2_.merchant_id
GROUP BY b0_.id,
  b0_.created,
  b1_.businessName,
  b1_.isVerified
ORDER BY b2_.created DESC
) a
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

And I am getting `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.
I read somewhere that I need to specify all columns that are not being used by aggregate functins in group by statement. I did so but the result is same.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong! Thanks!

Edit: I did `ORDER BY 2 DESC` and it worked in SQL Developer, But query builder wont take 2. So how do I do it in Doctrine2 querybuilder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your order by should be `ORDER BY b0_.created DESC` and not `ORDER BY b2_.created DESC`. When you tried `ORDER BY 2 DESC` it is working because you are ordering by 2nd column - `b0_.created`

Comment: ahhh, how could I not see that! I made it 2 because in select clause I could see its the second column, but in doctrine query builder I was ordering by a different alias (that was joined). Thanks much :)